# Backup FreeNAS on NTFS dive

Tags: backup, ntfs, freenas

**The Setup**

Scanner -> FreeNAS Via UNC Path

FreeNAS -> Clients Via UNC Path

The Clients are all Windows 7 Home Premium. (Ugh)

**The Question**

How can I automatically have one of the clients incrementally backup all the data on the server via UNC path?

**The Why**

If/when the FreeNAS box fails I will need to gain access to the files quickly. Having a external HDD that I could just plug into an exiting Windows box would be ideal. I'm not too worried about speed in this case.

**End Goal**

Have one client do an incremental backup on an external HDD.

**What I have done thus far**

Using Corbin Backup 10 with convert UNC paths off:

```
Mapped drive Z. The source directory "Z:\" doesn't exist.
```

Using Corbin Backup 10 with convert UNC paths on:

```
The source directory "\\FreeNAS\files\" doesn't exist.
```

Using Corbin Backup 10 with convert UNC paths on, impersonating NAS user:

```
The user local\<UserName> couldn't login: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password
The source directory "\\FreeNAS\files\" doesn't exist
```

Windows backup doesn't show the mapped dive as an option.

**Temp Fix**

I'm using xcopy as a temporary fix. I would us xxcopy but it requires an elevated cmd.